# Is this the correct way to use JS.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get a count of all the objects in an array (`this.players`) where object.alive == true.

So far I have:

```
return this.players.map(el => el.alive).reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    if(acc === true) {
      if(cur === true) {
        acc = 1
      } else {
        acc = 0
      }
    }
    return acc + ((cur) ? 1 : 0)
  })
```

which looks ugly as sin but appears to work. Is there a more robust way to do this?

Comment: It is not working correctly, returns `0` for `[{alive: true}, {alive: false}]`.

Comment: The `if (acc === true)` makes no sense, your accumulator is supposed to be a number. Pass `0` as a start value to `reduce`!

Comment: `acc` defaulted to true on the first iteration, I assume because the field type I am checking is a boolean. That is why I put the check in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.reduce` is a good choice as it avoids computation of a filtered array when you actually just want the number of `alive` players, not the players itself.

Your issue is within the `reduce` callback: `acc` accumulates the `number` of `alive` players, so you shouldn't compare it to `true`.

Also, instead of resetting that number via `acc = 1` or `acc = 0` you probably meant to write `acc += 1`.

Additionally, instead of mapping players to their `alive` property, just access that property directly within the reduce callback:

```js
let players = [{alive: true}, {alive: false}, {alive: false}, {alive: true}];

let alive = players.reduce((alive, next) => next.alive ? alive + 1 : alive, 0);

console.log(alive);
```

Comment: @khany No, it returns `0` for an empty array (which is the default value provided to the reduce method).

Answer (score 0):

Try filter, it works like map returning an array of filtered objects.

```
return this.players.filter(player => player.alive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) which creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
return this.players.filter(player => player.alive).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `filter` will be good for your case

```js
let players = [{alive: true}, {alive: false}, {alive: false}, {alive: true}]

let alivePlayersNum = players.filter( player =>  player.alive).length;

console.log(alivePlayersNum);
```